# How do I use Sinon to stub interaction with a database using mssql library?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sinon, node-mssql

Using the [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) library to pull data from SQL. I've been using Sinon for a while now (written about 200 tests with it); having a ton of trouble getting my head around how to stub this library out. The code looks like:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var conn = new sql.Connection(sqlConfig); // sqlConfig is connection info, defined elsewhere 

conn.connect(function(err) {
  var req, selectFromTable;
  if (err != null) {
    // handle error
  }
  req = new sql.Request(conn);
  selectFromTable = "select * from DW." + table + " where DWCreatedDate >= '" + start + "' and DWCreatedDate <= '" + end + "' ";
  logger.debug("Selecting with: ", selectFromTable);
  req.input('statement', sql.NVarChar, selectFromTable);
  return req.execute('sp_executesql', function(err, results, returnValue, affected) {
    if (err != null) {
      // etc.
    } else {
      // data processing   
    }
  });
});
```

Code works fine. Now I'm trying to write a test for it. I knew this library would be difficult to test so I procrastinated. My closest code:

```
var conn, reqExecute, sqlReqStub; 
sqlReqStub = sinon.stub(); 
sqlReqStub.execute = sinon.stub(); 
sinon.stub(sql, 'Request').returns(sqlReqStub); 
conn = sinon.stub(); 
sinon.stub(sql, 'Connection').returns(conn);

conn.connect = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(0, null);

reqExecute = sqlReqStub.execute.withArgs('sp_executesql').onFirstCall().callsArgWith(1, null, {
  a: 1
});
```

Your natural inclination might be to say "well, use `createStubInstance`" but when I use that I get back connection objects (`new sql.Connection(config)`) that have TediousRequest (what the library defaults to when it builds out the driver object inside of the connection) in them instead of my stub request. I can't find TediousRequest anywhere in the `sql` object to stub it out.

I'm stuck here; hoping someone has some code around that does this or can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did manage to solve it but it feels a little hacky for some reason. Possibly because I never figured out how to stub the `new sql.Request(conn)` call.

**Ideally** I'd like to get this working without having to include the sql library in my `module.exports`. I can do that with the `request` library but after a few hours knocking away at this library I'm unable to get it working in the same way.

First: export the sql library:

```
sql = require('mssql')
// much code
module.exports.sqlLib = sql
```

Second: stub things:

```
  var connection, sqlReqStub, sqlStubLib;
  var server = require('./index.js')    
  sqlStubLib = {};    
  connection = new EventEmitter();    
  connection.connected = true;    
  connection.close = function() {};    
  connection.connect = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(0, null);    
  sqlStubLib.Connect = sinon.stub();    
  sqlStubLib.Connection = function() {
    return connection;
  };    
  sqlReqStub = sinon.stub();    
  sqlReqStub.input = function() {};    
  sqlReqStub.execute = sinon.stub();    
  sqlReqStub.execute.withArgs('sp_executesql').onFirstCall().callsArgWith(1, null, [
    [
    // js object 
    ]
  ], null, null);

  sqlStubLib.Request = function() {
    return sqlReqStub;
  };

  server.sqlLib = sqlStubLib;
```