# How to test a function that is part of an object created by a required module in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, proxyquire

I have this module and the corresponding test with proxyquire.

```js
// sqlQuery.js
const sql = require('mssql');
module.exports = function sqlFn() {
  const request = new sql.Request();
}

// sqlQueryTest.js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sql = require('mssql');
let sqlStub = sinon.stub(sql);

describe('Sql wrapper', function() {

  let sqlQuery = proxyquire('../public/sqlQuery', {
    'sql': sqlStub
  })
  sqlQuery()

  it('Should call sql once', function() {
    expect(sqlStub.Request.callCount).to.deep.equal(1) // passes
  })

})
```

If in the `sqlQuery` I want to use the `request` object's functions, the test won't run:

`TypeError: request.query is not a function`

I tried `rewire` as well to set `require` to a stub:

```js
let stub1 = sinon.stub()
let sqlQuery = rewire('../public/sqlQuery')
sqlQuery.__set__('request', {
  input: stub1
})
```

How can I test if `request` is called with given methods in the code?

Comment: What is sql and how does it generate request? Is it mssql?  That means you probably have to mock the sql.createRequest (or whatever method creates the request object) and return a mock of the request. OO and mocking a big pain but if it's mssql you are using it seems someone did [most of the work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38646049/1641941).

Comment: Yes, it's mssql. I was hoping there is a better way of doing this, but the answer that @HMR linked looks like what I need.